# Howto add onclick event to button in listview added by addFooterView?

Tags: android

I'm using a listview with my own implementation of baseadapter. Before adding the main list items to the listview and setting the Adapter i add a footer, with addFooterView(), to the listview. The footer is a normal listview item with a custom view and two buttons.

And here comes my problem:

How can i add a onClick() event to this buttons? i tried it in the getView() method of my baseadapter but that does not work. :/

I need these two buttons at the bottom of my listview as back and forward buttons, cause i don't want too much items at once in the listview.

thx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the footer is just a normal `View`, you should be able to inflate the view, get a handle to the `Button` with `findViewById()` and add an `onClick()` handler.

Assuming that your footer is an XML layout:

```
View footer = View.inflate(this, R.layout.footer, null);
getListView().addFooterView(foot, null, false);

Button forward = footer.findViewById(R.id.forward);
forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
```

Hopefully, that's enough to get you started.

Comment: hi Erich, 
thx for your comment. Where and how can i add this handle? Can you give me a short dummycoder?

Comment: Hey Erich, i was sure i tested it like this before but without luck. :) anyway, thx for your time now it works. Nice to see helfull people like you. Have a nice day. I'm sure, i will need more held in the future and come back to you. ;)